# Can i scan EAN barcodes in meta quest 3 AR?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

for work i'm researching if could make an application that could scan an EAN code of a specific product and then show the product details on screen in AR. I looked online for a bit and found out that meta quest 3 has a lot of great function's that i could use (hand gestures/etc.) to make this application run better and that's why i chose meta 3. I can then for example use certain hand gestures to prompt the "start scanning" function, that tries to scan the EAN code. But i was wondering if i make a barcode scanner function in unity with vuforia, would this be able to work in meta quest 3?